# SonarQube 6.4, deprecated rules and how to fix them

Tags: sonarqube

I'm looking for a way to change deprecated rules in SonarQube. I've got my own Quantity configuration, but Sonar shows that there are 2 deprecated rules, it suggest mi other ones, but I have no idea how to change/fix them. I've looked through internet and google, but there's no asnwer, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggested replacement rules should be linked. Click through. Now you're on the detail page of the suggested replacement. At the bottom next to "Quality Profiles", assuming you're logged in with the correct permissions, you'll see an "Activate" button. Use it to turn the replacement on in your profile. Now you can go back to the deprecated rule and remove it from your quality profile.